# Anaconda environment is not finding installed packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to leverage conda environments to isolate the package and dependencies. 
Created conda environment and installed the packages. Still can't import and use the packages..

Here are my steps

```
==> conda create --name test biopython

==> source activate test

==> which python
/Users/sahaswaranamam/anaconda/envs/test/bin/python

==> pip install google_search
...installation happens here...

==> ipython
In [1]: import google_search
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-676be9f470ae> in <module>()
----> 1 import google_search

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_search'
```

Comment: just out of interest what does `which pip` and `which ipython` return?

Comment: ==> which pip
/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/test/bin/pip
==> which ipython
/Users/xyz/anaconda/envs/test/bin/ipython

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you have installed

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-search/1.0.2

According to the document, you may use:

```
import googlesearch
```

Make sure that you did not want to install search-google, which seems to be more popular (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/search-google/1.0.4)

Comment: ==> pip install googlesearch
Collecting googlesearch
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googlesearch (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for googlesearch

Comment: @Sahas you have installed google-search (via `pip install google_search`). So you can use it via `import googlesearch`